# saving huxtable to word loses the number formatting

Tags: ms-word, formatting, numbers, huxtable

I have created a table of my data in r using huxtable. The formatting of the numbers is very important and conditional across the table. In r, when I look at my huxtable the formatting is perfect. When I use quick_docx to save it to work, it changes some of my number formatting. For example, 1.008 gets turned into a round 1. Is there a way to save the formatting exactly as it is in my huxtable?

Comment: Try `set_number_format()`. If that fails, file a bug.

Comment: @dash2 yes I have used set_number_format() and it works when I view the Huxtable in r. However, when I save it as a word document some of the formatting changes. I will file a bug.